# get only ONE value of database by php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in this world, so any help is grateful for me.

I want to get only ONE value of my database and see it in my website.

By phpmyadmin I create a db and then a table.

This is my table:

[image]

[image]

I want to see in my website '**Máscara**' by knowledge of id

Okey so in my .php  archive, firt of all, I have created the conexion

```
<?php

$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "practicas";

// creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

// Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

echo "All okey";
?>
```

So far, It's okay. My problems start now. I have found many example to print all table data but nothing about print one value.

I know that I have to create the query:

```
    $query= Select from tablapractica1 nombre where id=20
    echo $query
```

But I don't know how traduce it to a code to see that data in the web.

So, please, can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Then I suggest you hit the manual and the tutorials. There are hundred of them on the web as SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your query, it should be formed like this:

```
$query = "select nombre from tablapractica1 where id = 20";
```

and you must first send your query to the MySQL server using a mysqli_query($conexion, $query) call.  It will prepare and return a result set for you to read.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
```

Then, you must fetch one record at a time from the result set.  In this case, there should only be 1 record because you are fetching id = 20 .  You will typically use mysqli_fetch_array($result) to return an array of the data, or you can use mysqli_fetch_object($result) to return an object of the data.

```
$record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Lastly, you can echo the record in the array (in this example when using mysqli_fetch_array() above)

```
echo 'nombre=' . $record['nombre'];
```

Putting this all together would look like this:

```
// query
$query = "select nombre from tablapractica1 where id = 20";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo 'nombre=' . $record['nombre'];
```

If you have multiple records in your table, you can use a while loop to iterate through the data like this:

```
// query
$query = "select nombre from tablapractica1 where nombre like 'Vidal'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo 'nombre=' . $record['nombre'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to the world of coding.
You have little bit issue with the code.
Try this.

Pass query. You should use connection variable along with query in mysqli

```
 $query= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT `nombre` FROM `tablapractica1` WHERE `id` = '20' ") or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Get result of the query into a variable

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

//Print the output

```
echo $row['nombre'];
```

**Dont get confused with the ( '  - single quote - used for value 20) and ( `  -  used with field name and table name)**